# JQuery control for line chart with trend cursor (x-axis line overlay with values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, ignite-ui

**The Problem:**

I’m looking to create a line chart in html/javascript/jquery to display data in a similar fashion to this old chart control in Citect software I have used. Basically a line chart with tooltips for current y-axis values for selected x-axis value. In the Citect software they call this vertical line with values a trend cursor.

In this image below there are 3 series and by dragging the trend cursor you can see the values for all 3 series for a given time.

[image: Trend Cursor Sample]

**My environment & intended approach:**

Due to multiple series with different y-axis ranges I am planning on stacking line charts (rather than scaling), if I can get the 'trend cursor' to drag on all charts at the same time so it look/feels like one control this would be ideal.

I'm trying to use html5/jquery etc. and aiming for a responsive UI that will work for desktops/tablets and mobile devices. But am open to using an asp.net control on an aspx form if there's nothing that can be easily configured in html/javascript.

Worth noting is that I have the Infragistics Ignite UI control library, their support suggested using a crosshair which doesn't suit my needs. I think it is possible to use the data chart control  but being new to web programming and these products it's hard to find the information I need in their help to get started.

**Key features required:**

- Vertical line, dragged along x-axis
- Display values where vertical intersects series
- Can remove mouse and line/labels stay put
- Multiple stacked series, line state consistent if stacked charts used.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try http://d3js.org/
it has a lot of features and a bunch of tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've had a look, but can't see how I will implement a line chart with draggable vertical line overlaid showing corresponding series y-value where it intersects. If you can explain the steps or even better show a sample with jsfiddle I'll accept this answer.